# Git altering binary files when cloning

Tags: windows, git, github

I'm just getting started with git and am running into a problem when attempting to clone a respository from github. There are several binary files (.exe and .dll) contained in the repo; when I make a clone of this on my local machine none of these binaries are valid (as far as windows is concerned). Attempting to execute them results in the following message being displayed:

> 'XXX is not a valid Win32 application'

I *believe* I have everything setup properly, (using GitExtensions, if that's relevant) - but I can't seem to get this issue resolved.

Any help much appreciated!

**Edit:**

This is my current .gitconfig - if relevant:

```
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = c:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
[diff]
    guitool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = c:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
[core]
    editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe\" fileeditor
    autocrlf = true
```

Comment: You could start by checking if files have same or different checksums

Comment: @CharlesB: I can tell that git is certainly doing something with the binaries; as they are different sizes than ones downloaded manually out of the repo (eg. download zip file of master from github)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have fallen foul of line endings fix up's - and it not treating the files as binary:

> For example, if you want all *.foo
>   files to be treated as binary files
>   you can have this line in
>   .gitattributes:

```
*.foo -crlf -diff -merge
```

> This will mean all files with a .foo extension
>   will not have carriage return/line
>   feed translations done, won't be
>   diffed and merges will result in
>   conflicts leaving the original file
>   untouched.

Source info:
About the line endings: http://help.github.com/dealing-with-lineendings/

About Binary files: http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2007/09/git-binary-files-and-cherry-picking.html .

Comment: Thanks for this, I did read that initial article and *thought* I had followed the directions; I've updated my question to include my .gitconfig if helpful.

Comment: @DanP: You haven't really addressed Danny's suggestion - git could be detecting your binary files as text files, and applying the autocrlf transformation. Try setting the git attributes as described and see if it prevents mangling.

Comment: I've attempted to add *.ddl and *.exe files to my .gitattributes file in my user dir, still running into the same problems. I should note that the repo itself has these files with different settings - is this overriding my global config?

Comment: turns out the problem was at the repo end; but this *would* have been the right answer if that wasn't the case - thanks!